# How to skip a malformed line when using TextFieldParser?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `TextFieldParser` to parse csv files. Tt works fine if it is a well formed csv. However, in some cases, some lines have malformed csv format:

> 111,2222,"3333',4444, 555

I'm using code like this:

```
using (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser MyReader = new
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(@"C:\myData.csv"))
{
    MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
    MyReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "\t", "," });
    MyReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    MyReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    MyReader.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    //MyReader.

    while (!MyReader.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] fields = MyReader.ReadFields();
            Debug.WriteLine(fields.Length.ToString());
        }
        catch (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Line " + ex.LineNumber.ToString() + 
                "is not valid and will be skipped: " + MyReader.ErrorLine + 
                "\r\n\r\n" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

For some reasons, it catches `MalformedLineException`, but `MyReader.EndOfData` is true after that even when there are some lines after it.

Is this by design? Any way to let it skip the malformed line, and parse the lines after it?

Thanks

Comment: See if this [FIX: The TextFieldParser.EndOfData method returns True when the TextFieldParser object does not reach the end of text data in a Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0-based application or a Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1-based application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2254512) applies to you

Comment: no, it is not because of that. I think it is by design. Because the line is malformed. it has one ", Parser tries to find the next ", but could not find it until the end of the csv file. That's why it reached the end of file. It should have a property that tells parser that in the quoted fields, there is no end of line allowed. If it is allowed, it will have this issue.

Comment: I didn't get the chance to try it, but what if you added `\r` and `\n` to the list of delimiters? It might not fall in your try-catch block, but you can validate on the number of fields.

Comment: And scratch my idea, I get an `ArgumentException` on `SetDelimiters`: "TextFieldParser does not support delimiters that contain end-of-line characters."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any way the program continue read the file.
But try this code.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
...
private void ReadFunction()
{
    using (TextFieldParser MyReader =
        new TextFieldParser(@"C:\temp\myData.csv"))
    {
        int lineRead = 1;
        while (!MyReader.EndOfData)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] fields = ParseHelper(MyReader.ReadLine(), lineRead++);
                Console.WriteLine(fields.Length.ToString());
            }
            catch (MalformedLineException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);          
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

private string[] ParseHelper(String line, int lineRead)
{
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(line));
    TextFieldParser ReaderTemp = new TextFieldParser(mem);
    ReaderTemp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    ReaderTemp.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "\t", "," });
    ReaderTemp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    ReaderTemp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    ReaderTemp.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    try
    {
        return ReaderTemp.ReadFields();
    }
    catch (MalformedLineException ex)
    {
        throw new MalformedLineException(String.Format(
            "Line {0} is not valid and will be skipped: {1}\r\n\r\n{2}",
            lineRead,ReaderTemp.ErrorLine, ex));
    }
}
```

Instead use `using (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser MyReader = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(@"C:\temp\myData.csv"))` you can use a FileStrean to read a text file and pass line by line to the function ParseHelper;

I hope this help you.

Comment: thanks. it is a good idea if we want to stick to TextFieldParser. in my case, we decided to write our own csv parser since we have special requirements for malformed csv.

Comment: Why did you initialize TextFieldType 2 times in your helper function?

Comment: @Samuel what happens if a string field ( with quotes around it ) has a New Line ( \n ) in it? Would it not break the above logic?